# how to calculate first order derivative of matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace, matrix-norms

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the first order derivative of matrix, and was wondering if anyone could help me.

The function with respect to P is

f(P)=*Tr*($XPAP^TPA^TP^TX^T$)=$||XPAP^T||^2_F$

where *Tr* is the trace, $A$ and $X$ are matrix.

The derivative of *Tr(AP)* is $A^T$, but how to calculate the derivative of f(P) which contains the fourth power of P?

Apologises for the poor wording of this question!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First, introduce a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
M &= XPAP^T \quad\implies\quad
dM = (X\,dP\,AP^T &+\;\;\; XPA\;dP^T)
}$$
Then, calculate the *differential* of the function
$$\eqalign{
f &= M:M \\
df
  &= 2M:dM \\
  &= 2(XPAP^T) : (X\,dP\,AP^T &+\;\;\; XPA\;dP^T) \\
  &= (2XPAP^T) : (X\,dP\,AP^T) &+\;\;\; (2PA^TP^TX^T):(dP\,A^TP^TX^T) \\
  &= (2X^TXPAP^TPA^T):dP &+\;\;\; (2PA^TP^TX^TXPA):dP \\
  &= \Big(2X^TXPAP^TPA^T &+\;\;\; 2PA^TP^TX^TXPA\Big):dP \\
}$$
From this result, the gradient can be identified as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}
  &= 2X^TXPAP^TPA^T \;+\; 2P\,A^TP^TX^TXPA
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad\;\; \\\\ 
}$$
**NB:** $\;$In the above derivation, a colon denotes the [double-dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product)

Comment: I don't get it, does he want 1st (post) or 4th derivative (title)?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got first term with $dX$ in 3rd line, please? Thank you.

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Does the update help? I think the OP got confused by invoking the chain rule, which would require a 4th order tensor as an intermediate quantity in calculating the gradient of $f$.

Comment: Not really, I don't get where the $dX$ comes from in the next line you treat it like $dP$. I'm lost at
$$2(XPAP^\top) : (XdPAP^\top)+2(XPAP^\top) : (XPAdP^\top)$$.

Comment: Apologises for the incorrect description of the title. I want to calculate the first derivative.  In addition, I have the same problem as @JoanS.GuillametF. Would you please explaining how to get $(2X^TXPAP^TPA^T):dX$ from $(2XPAP^T):XdPAP^T$ . Thank you in advance!

Comment: I apologize, the $dX$ was simply a typo.  It has been corrected to $dP\;$